# There is no catalina.out

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, catalina.out

I have no idea, how and what to set up, to have catalina.out on the Tomcat on my computer.

I use Tomcat 6.0.28, zipped-version on Windows XP. To start server I just run startup.bat-file.

Do I do something wrong?!

Thanks in advance for any advices.

Mur

[Edited]
All records (Exceptions or System.out) will be written in console window. Where to set up, that they would be written to catalina.out?

As I wrote in one of my comments, if I install Tomcat with setup-version, all messages occur in stdout_YYYYMMDD.log and I don't see, where to change this.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like Tomcat 6 on Windows does not write to catalina.out

I can see why this is happening, but not sure where to fix it.

catalina.sh has this line which sends the System outs into catalina.out

```
"$CATALINA_BASE"/logs/catalina.out 2>&1
```

this line is missing from catalina.bat which is why this does not appear on windows.

Comment: Thank you. I tried your solution, but ... I just give up. It's really the easiest way to install Tomcat from setup-file on Windows to output all logs into a log-file.

Answer (score 4):

I have written a batch file 'start&log.bat' and put it in tomcat\bin directory. The batch file has one line:

```
catalina run > ..\logs\catalina.out 2<&1
```

Comment: Hi Mark. I know this is a bit out of date, but I cannot get this to work. Is there anything else I need to add to the batch file? I am still not getting a catalina.out, despite errors. Thanks!

Comment: @IliaKoulikov it works for me though,is your problem solved or you want my help?

Comment: Thanks, SpringLearner, but I've found a way around it since then.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running any applications with the application server as I think it only creates the file when there is an error in an application.

Comment: No, it created no file also in error case. At least I think so. I try to produce some errors and will see.

And I've installed for 5 minutes executable version of Tomcat. Now it writes logs now, but there is still no catalina.out, but at least something.

Can I setup my application to write logs into catalina.out and if yes, how?!

Comment: Also errors will be written in stdout_YYYYMMDD.log (today in stdout_20100816.log), but I would like to have them in catalina.out.
Some Ideas?

Answer (score -2):

my experience is that these logs are always produced somewhere, even if not in catalina.out.  on Linux 7 tomcat7 yum installed, my system.out.println( messages end up in /var/log/message.  fine with me, as long as I can find them.  found them there with grep -r 'system.out.println(' *  from root directory.  Command takes a long time to run.