# Apache Tomcat is showing directory list instead of a simple web page

Tags: java, xml, tomcat

I am trying to make my first web application with java servlet, apache tomcat and java. This are my directories
[image]

[image]

[image]

This is my java file saved as HelloServlet.java

```
import java.io.*;
import jakarta.servlet.*;
import jakarta.servlet.http.*;
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet{
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException{
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html>\n\t<head>\n\t\t<title>Hello!</title>\n\t</head>");
        out.println("\t<body>\n\t\tHello, world.\n\t</body>");
    }
}
```

The java file compiled just fine no problem there.

This is my web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Web-app
PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 
2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/Web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app>
    <display-name>The Hello World Application</display-name>
    <description>Prints hello world!</description>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
        <description>This is a simple Servlet</description>
        <servlet-class>HelloServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</Web-app>
```

Apache Tomcat is successfully installed and running just fine I changed the port number to 8888 which was also just fine.

but if I visit http://localhost:8888/hello I get a directory list of the folder hello instead of a simple web page with Hello, world. Why so?

Comment: STRONG SUGGESTION: consider developing your Java servlets in an IDE like Eclipse or Netbeans.

Comment: I will this is the first one

Comment: When you visit http://localhost:8888/ do you see a page branded with Apache Tomcat?

Comment: check your catalina.out log file

Comment: @BasilBourque Yes I do

Comment: @ScaryWombat Do I find it here C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.0\logs

Comment: @ScaryWombat I searched catalina.out in tomcat10.0 folder no items matched my search

Comment: @ScaryWombat based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/8239570/16430624 I do have three files  catalina.2022-05-24, catalina.2022-05-26 and catalina.2022-05-27 in C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.0\logs

Comment: Well I would check the catalina.2022-05-27 file and search for **hello** (the name of your webapp).  Are there some errors?  As you *see a page branded with Apache Tomcat* it seems loading the webapp is the likely problem.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Let me see that, but interestingly i have renamed the folder Web-INF to WEB-INF and now I don't see directory list but error HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

Comment: @ScaryWombat Thanks a lot, the error was <web-app> must be closed by </web-app> not </Web-app> can't believe I didn't see that. Figured that out in catalina.2022-05-27 file. Thanks again

Comment: I also think naming the folder Web-INF was also a problem. It led to the directory list

Comment: | can't believe I didn't see that - can not un-see it now

Comment: I suggest you draft, post, and accept an Answer to your own Question, for posterity.

Comment: Using tools to auto-generate this boilerplate would avoid the hassle of your understandable typos. Humans are not good at trivial details, while computers are. For example, choosing *File > New Project > Generators > Java Enterprise* in IntelliJ will create a complete project with a sample JSP page and a sample Servlet. Both the `WEB-INF` folder and its nested `web.xml` file are created automatically for you.

Comment: Try <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>